# AJAX is not working properly after moving on localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, localhost

I have an issue with my simple testing code. Everything was fine on remote server, it starts when I moved to localhost(xampp)

I have a page:

http://localhost/test/test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>NeedNext - Try It</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$().ready(function() {
    $("#listinx").load("ajax.php",{variable : "WTF"})
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="listinx"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

called http://localhost/test/ajax.php contains:

```
<?php
echo "heh?";
echo $variable;
?>
```

I suppose the result in browser should be: "heh?WTF" but it's only "heh?". Any ideas what's wrong?
Please let me know,
Thanks,
Michal

Comment: What does ajax.php do?  Just return the variable "variable" sent to it?

Comment: You should write `$(function() { ... });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
echo $_REQUEST['variable'];
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) enabled.
Therefore, you cannot implicitly get POST parameters by writing `$variable`.

Change your code to `echo $_POST['variable']`.

You should also disable it on your server:

> ## Warning
>
> This feature has been ***DEPRECATED*** as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

It will usually create security holes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is really the issue! but $POST wasn't working, only $_REQUEST

Comment: @Michal: I forgot the `_`.  Fixed.