# What settings in php.ini should I adjust for php to accept data from javascript?

Tags: php

I just installed LAMP.  Everything seems to be working fine except when I send data from js to php via ajax, php does not receive the data sent.  I suspect this has to do with a setting in php.ini but I don't know which to change.  My js ajax function looks like this:

function ajax (url, data_to_be_sent, callback_func) {

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

}

else

{// code for IE6, IE5

    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=callback_func;

xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.send(data_to_be_sent);
```

}

Comment: It's nothing to do with the request being from Javascript, or anything in php.ini

Comment: what is in `data_to_be_sent`? it is supposed to be an url_encoded query string, e.g. `param1=value1&param2=value2`, is that what you're sending?

Comment: Yes. data_to_be_sent is exactly param1=value1&param2=value2.

Comment: Btw, I'd recommend you use something like jQuery or Mootools - they have libraries to deal with all the low-level AJAX stuff for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to do:

1. Debug your client side Javascript to verify you're making the right call, with the right URL string.
2. Look at your server side logs to see if any client-side requests are being made, and if there are any errors.

This really has nothing to do with PHP, and messing with php.ini isn't going to help.

PS:
You're using something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript), aren't you?

Comment: I guess I should start using a debug program.  The funny thing about this is the ajax calls work perfectly fine on a public server but not on localhost.  Thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: Actually, look at this link about using $POST variables:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985997/ajax-is-not-working-properly-after-moving-on-localhost

Comment: The link you provided was exactly what I needed. I could either change the register_globals setting to on or keep it off and use $_POST['variable'] instead of $variable to get at my variables.  Thanks a lot paulsm4.

Comment: Don't use register_globals - it will disappear from a future version of PHP.